# Error when running the command minikube start

Tags: docker, minikube

The following error when I run the command `minikube start` :

Unable to pick a default driver. Here is what was considered, in preference order:
▪ docker: Not healthy: "docker version --format {{.Server.Os}}-{{.Server.Version}}" exit status 1: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
▪ docker: Suggestion: Add your user to the 'docker' group: 'sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker' https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
  Alternatively you could install one of these drivers:
▪ kvm2: Not installed: exec: "virsh": executable file not found in $PATH
▪ vmware: Not installed: exec: "docker-machine-driver-vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
▪ podman: Not installed: exec: "podman": executable file not found in $PATH
▪ virtualbox: Not installed: unable to find VBoxManage in $PATH

❌  Exiting due to DRV_NOT_HEALTHY: Found driver(s) but none were healthy. See above for suggestions how to fix installed drivers.

Comment: While posting questions, try to give some more information on what you are trying to do. the steps you have tried, and if there is any code written by you. The configuration that you are attempting on. this will make it more helpful for people trying to answer

Comment: There is an issue in the GitHub project: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13014 - the related PR that fixes the issue says "When minikube is unable to pick a default driver the installed drivers is shown separately with appropriate messages and the non-installed drivers is displayed in a separate list with appropriate messages" - the list displays driver that are not installed. If you have the drivers installed, I'd concentrate on the "permission denied" issue in line 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you need root access to run the command, try adding your user to the docker group with this command:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker
```

after that restart the terminal and run the command again to check if it works

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on linux:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
sudo addgroup --system docker
sudo adduser #USER docker
newgrp docker
```

where #USER is your current username
Restart the terminal and it will work out